# Can't get Internet connectivity from access point connected to Zyxel firewall

Tags: wireless-router, firewall, internet-connection, wireless-access-point

I have an access point I'm trying to make accessible.

- My access point is a LinkSys E1200 wireless router in bridged mode.
- I have a CAT5 cable going from its WAN port to P4 on a Zyxel USG50 firewall.
- P4 is configured as ext-wlan with the following information:

  - IP address `192.168.0.64/27`.
  - DHCP enabled with pool starting at `192.168. 0.68` and continuing until `192.168.0.95`.

If I connect my computer to P4 and set my NIC to grab an IP via DHCP, I'm able to successfully grab the IP `192.168.0.68/27` with the default gateway `192.168.0.64` and connect to the Internet.

- The WAN connection on the LinkSys set to grab an IP via DHCP and its LAN connection set to `192.168.0.66/27` with a default gateway of `192.168.0.64`.
- The DHCP Server and firewall are disabled on the LinkSys.
- Authentication is set to WPA-Personal with TKIP + AES and a passkey is enabled.

The main router I'm using that's connected between my modem and my firewall is another LinkSys device. It has its wireless and DHCP server and firewall disabled and it has an IP address of `192.168.0.1/24`.

I can technically connect to the AP and enter in the passkey, but there's no Internet connectivity. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: The highest usable IP address in that range is 192.168.0.94. Maybe the firewall is assigning you 129.168.0.95, which is unusable since it's a broadcast address.

Comment: Also, something's off with your description. If you set the Internet Connection to bridge mode, you cannot also set it to get an IP via DHCP. In bridged mode, there is only one IP configuration.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz To my knowledge the E1200 doesn't support bridged mode...though I admit it's been a while since I've seen that unit's configuration options.

Comment: Which device is configured to do NAT for devices in the 192.168.0.64/27 subnet? If none, then that's your problem. (Also, if the device doesn't have bridged mode, you should just leave the WAN port empty and connect LAN to LAN.)

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I'm going to revisit all the steps I took and try out your suggestions. I'll get back to this topic with the solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too low level to "reply" so i try here:

Maybe your next step could be to try a fixed ip to exclude a possible dhcp error even tho you tried thaz on LAN interface.

Or: Startmenu -> Run -> ipconfig /all
Do you get a ip, gateway and dns adress?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you expect your Zyxel firewall to protect your wireless clients and don't need any firewall services from your Linksys E1200 (which, as you've noted, you don't have its firewall enabled), then you don't need to run the connection through the E1200's WAN port.  Instead:

1. Assign an IP to your LinkSys E1200 in the subnet of your firewall's P4 switch port. For example, use `192.168.0.65/27`
2. Move the Ethernet cable coming from the from the Zyxel firewall to one of the LinkSys E1200's LAN ports.

When clients connect wirelessly to the E1200, they are in its LAN zone. Therefore, traffic from these clients will flow to the Zyxel firewall's P4 port, enabling the wireless clients to pick up a DHCP address in the `192.168.0.64/27` subnetwork and properly connect to the Internet. Further, because you've assigned the E1200 an IP in the same subnetwork, you'll continue to have access to it for management purposes.

Comment: I ended up being able to connect once I set the LinkSys E1200 in bridge mode and let it grab an IP address via DHCP from the pool made available for P4 on the Zyxel USG 50. I wasn't able to get Internet connectivity when I gave the LinkSys E1200 a static IP in the 192.168.0.64/27 subnet, so I will revisit why my static IP wasn't working whereas my DHCP-assigned one was. I tried using both a .64 and .65 default gateway, but no joy with either one.